# Attach Google Slide as a pdf with the placeholder text replaced whilst sending by email

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-slides

I have drafted the below code however it attached the pdf with the placeholders.
[image]

The below code takes data from a google form populates it on a google sheet and replaces all the placeholders on the template with the data from the google form. The trigger 'on form submit' has been added.
The code is as follows:

```
function DigitalReceipts() {

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Receipts").activate();

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var lr = ss.getLastRow()

  for (var i =2;i<lr;i++){

    if(ss.getRange(i, 1).getValue()){

  //Make a copy of the template file - power point
  var documentId = DriveApp.getFileById('1FtgZuJb4KpChhgehPp1lIEtrsjvykAqRiYl5rL8yv2Q').makeCopy().getId();

  var RV = ss.getRange(i, 2).getValue();

  var DateFormat = ss.getRange(i, 4).getValue();
  var Date = Utilities.formatDate(DateFormat, "GMT+0400", "dd MMM yyyy");   

  var Amount = ss.getRange(i, 5).getValue().toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
  var Name = ss.getRange(i, 6).getValue();
  var Description = ss.getRange(i, 7).getValue();
  var SalesOwner = ss.getRange(i, 8).getValue();
  var PaymentType = ss.getRange(i, 9).getValue();
  var PaymentReference = ss.getRange(i, 10).getValue();    

  //Get the document body as a variable
  var body = SlidesApp.openById(documentId);

  body.replaceAllText('{RV}', RV);
  body.replaceAllText('{Date}', Date);
  body.replaceAllText('{Amount}', Amount);
  body.replaceAllText('{Name}', Name);
  body.replaceAllText('{Description}', Description);
  body.replaceAllText('{Sales Owner}', SalesOwner); 
  body.replaceAllText('{Payment Type}', PaymentType); 
  body.replaceAllText('{Payment Reference}', PaymentReference); 

  DriveApp.getFileById(documentId).setName("xxx_"+Name+"_Receipt_"+RV);

  //var body = DocumentApp.openById(documentId).getBody();

  //body.replaceText('{RV}', RV).replaceText('{Date}', Date).replaceText('{Amount}', Amount).replaceText('{Name}', Name).replaceText('{Description}', Description).replaceText('{Sales Owner}', SalesOwner).replaceText('{Payment Type}', PaymentType).replaceText('{Payment Reference}', PaymentReference);

  var receipt = body.getSlides();
  var receiptNumber = 1;

  //var receiptURL = body.getId()+receipt[receiptNumber-1].getObjectId();    
  var receiptURL = body.getUrl()+"#slide=id."+receipt[receiptNumber-1].getObjectId();
  ss.getRange(i, 11).setValue(receiptURL);  

      var currentEmail = ss.getRange(i, 3).getValue();
      var subjectLine = "PwC's Academy_"+Name+"_Receipt_"+RV;
      var templateText =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Template").getRange(1, 1).getValue();
      var messageBody = templateText.replace("{Name}", Name).replace("{Description}", Description).replace("{URL}", receiptURL);

      //var ReceiptID = ss.getRange(i, 11).getValue();
      //var ReceiptID = ReceiptURL.match(/[-\w]{25,}/);


   //var ReceiptAttachment = ss.getRange(i, 11).getValue();          

   //var waiver = DriveApp.getFileById(ReceiptAttachment);
   //var liabilityWaiver = waiver.getAs(MimeType.PDF);


  var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(documentId).getAs("application/pdf");    

  MailApp.sendEmail(currentEmail, subjectLine, messageBody, {attachments: pdf,
                                                             cc: 'abc@abc.com'});

       }
     else {}
    }
}
```

Would be grateful for any help/guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### From:

```
body.replaceAllText('{Payment Reference}', PaymentReference); 

DriveApp.getFileById(documentId).setName("xxx_"+Name+"_Receipt_"+RV);
```

#### To:

```
body.replaceAllText('{Payment Reference}', PaymentReference); 
body.saveAndClose();  // <--- Added
DriveApp.getFileById(documentId).setName("xxx_"+Name+"_Receipt_"+RV);
```

#### Reference:

- [saveAndClose()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/presentation#saveandclose)

If this was not the direct solution of your issue, I apologize.