Incorrect resulting file content when creating file from blob
I'm trying to do sth fairly basic with a Google script: convert a Google slides doc to PDF. I need to do so after copying a slides template and altering it.
But when I use the following code after creating and modifying slides, the generated PDF does not include the changes I made.
var slidesCopy = template.makeCopy(destination).setName(presName);

// (...) Applying changes to the "slidesCopy" file (slides)

var fileId = slidesCopy.getId();
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
var blob = file.getBlob();
var PDFfile = DriveApp.createFile(blob);

Logger.log('PDF URL: '+PDFfile.getUrl());

The resulting PDF file is there, but its content does not include the changes originally applied, while its name doesn't even match slidesCopy's - before or after the changes.
Looking at the generated Google Slides document ('slidesCopy'), I can see the changes are there.
Would anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Although, unfortunately, I cannot know your whole script, in your showing script, please add SlidesApp.openById(fileId).saveAndClose() just after the line of var fileId = slidesCopy.getId();, and test it again. If that is a solution to your issue, I guess that this question might be a duplicate question. https://stackoverflow.com/q/60310546
